# Why does the # character appear when using Angular ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

What does # character mean in a url and why does it appear when using angular routing:

```
http://localhost:8000/#/login
http://localhost:8000/#/register
```

How can i make the link look like: `http://localhost:8000/register`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **HTML 5 MODE** to `true`...

have a look at: [Angular JS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

Answer (score 2):

Angular load template asynchronous. for navigate one view to second view use # sign like go to any ID in javascript. but if you not want to appear in URL then use.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In you config phase.

Answer (score 1):

An Angular application is a single-page application. Without the #, you would move from one page to another instead of staying on the same page.
The # sign is used in the URI of an HTML page to navigate within the page.